# CAShapeLayer cornerRadius isn't working on UIBezierPath

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Hi guys the code below makes a little gray rectangle with a dark border. The corner radio isn't working and I cannot figure out why, I've tried applying maskToBounds = true, but that just hides the whole object...

How can I achieve this? Thanks

```
CGRect r = CGRectMake(conX, conY, 220, 50);
    UIBezierPath* conPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:r];
    CAShapeLayer* conLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    conLayer.path = conPath.CGPath;
    conLayer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
    UIColor *bg = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:0.7];
    [conLayer setFillColor:bg.CGColor];
    [conLayer setStrokeColor:[UIColor grayColor].CGColor];
    [[self layer] addSublayer:conLayer];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

UPDATE:

You can simply use `UIBezierPath( roundedRect: CGRect, cornerRadius: CGFloat).CGPath` to create your round rect path

---

I recommend using a round rect path instead:

```
CGRect r = { .size = { 220.0f, 50.0f } } ;

CAShapeLayer * layer = [ CAShapeLayer layer ] ;
layer.path = CGPathCreateRoundRect( r, 5.0f ) ;
```

where `CGPathCreateRoundRect()` is

```
CGPathRef CGPathCreateRoundRect( const CGRect r, const CGFloat cornerRadius )
{
    CGMutablePathRef p = CGPathCreateMutable() ;

    CGPathMoveToPoint( p, NULL, r.origin.x + cornerRadius, r.origin.y ) ;

    CGFloat maxX = CGRectGetMaxX( r ) ;
    CGFloat maxY = CGRectGetMaxY( r ) ;

    CGPathAddArcToPoint( p, NULL, maxX, r.origin.y, maxX, r.origin.y + cornerRadius, cornerRadius ) ;
    CGPathAddArcToPoint( p, NULL, maxX, maxY, maxX - cornerRadius, maxY, cornerRadius ) ;

    CGPathAddArcToPoint( p, NULL, r.origin.x, maxY, r.origin.x, maxY - cornerRadius, cornerRadius ) ;
    CGPathAddArcToPoint( p, NULL, r.origin.x, r.origin.y, r.origin.x + cornerRadius, r.origin.y, cornerRadius ) ;

    return p ;
}
```

Comment: if it's a masking effect you want, set your layer's __mask__ property to a shape layer with a round rect path

Comment: Thanks Niels thats awesome mate! :D)